# What do I need to play 3D games other than a 3D TV?

Tags: stereo-3d, monitor

I am planning on buying a 3D TV (Sony 3D Bravia) and using its 3D features with my PC.

What else should I need for this? Will an nVidia nVision card be enough?

Answer (score 7):

To be able to use a 3D TV for computer gaming you need the following items:

1. 3D TV.
2. 3D Glasses.
3. A HDMI 1.4a cable.
4. A graphics card able to transmit 3D images.

It is very important that you use a HDMI 1.4 or 1.4a cable, because earlier versions of the cable cannot transmit the frequencies needed for 3D.

As for the graphics card in your computer, both AMD and Nvidia are manufacturing capable video cards.

For Nvidia take a look at this [list](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-requirements.html).

For AMD take a look at this [list](http://products.amd.com/en-us/workstationgraphiccardresult.aspx?f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=Full%20Height/Full%20Length&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&f12=&f13=True&f14=&f15=&).

Note AMD Uses DisplayPort on some graphics cards. A DisplayPort to HDMI cable is need if the TV does not have a DisplayPort input.
For DisplayPort cables you will need a 1.2 or higher, version of the cable (for same reason as with HDMI.)

When choosing a 3D TV keep in mind that there are several ways of sending the 3D signal to the TV, and therefor you must make sure the TV supports the incomming signal.

There are, currently, four different methods of sending the signal:

- Side-By-Side
- Top and Bottom (or Over/Under)
- RealD
- SENSIO Hi-Fi 3D

Where the most common is Side-By-Side. However the Sony 3D Bravia supports both Side-By-Side and Over/Under.

Comment: Some games, such as DOOM 3 BFG, have software 3D side-by-side, so you do not need 3D card

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the spiel for the nVidia 3D Vision (I guess this is what you mean when you say "nVision") - then all you need is a 3D display device once you have the card:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-3d-games.html

I'm not entirely convinced at how good the 3D experience of many of the existing games in the list will be, since they were not specifically written for the technology. Still, I guess the parallaxing between left and right eye can be calculated on the fly by the hardware.

I found this review while I was looking around:

http://www.cnet.com.au/nvidia-geforce-3d-vision-kit-339301911.htm

> When it works, the kit's 3D effect is very convincing. For us though, it just didn't work consistently enough to justify its price or warrant a stronger recommendation.

Comment: for nVidia 3D Vision and nVidia 3D Play you still need the IR emitter (you can however use your TV's 3D glasses if using your TV).

Comment: UPDATE: actually you just need 3DTV Play with your 3D TV, you don't need the IR emitter and you use your TV glasses